# Parsing list in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm not too familiar with how to classify the data as an array and parsing through it with excel.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

cell A1 has `["1","2","3"]`

I'm trying to create a formula that will turn that into

```
<aa>1</aa><aa>2</aa><aa>3</aa>
```

I don't know how I'd turn cell A1 into an array for VBA to loop.

Answer (score 2):

No VBA required. In cell `B1` paste this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)&",",""",","</aa>"),"""","<aa>")
```

And here's a slightly shorter version built from @JvdV's comment. It uses one less function call... but one more string concatenation.

```
="<aa>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)-4),""",""","</aa><aa>")&"</aa>"
```

Comment: @JvdV Your formula leaves several quotation marks in the result. It does not work properly.

Comment: @JvdV I fixed it for you:  `="<aa>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)-4),""",""","</aa><aa>")&"</aa>"`

Comment: Somewhere those tripppe quotes got lost in the translation engine. =)

Answer (score 0):

Just parsed it manually. If anyone has a better way, I'd like to learn. Thanks!

```
Function ParseList(str As String)
    
    str = Replace(str, Chr(34), "")
    str = Replace(str, "[", "")
    str = Replace(str, "]", "")
    
    Dim LArray() As String
    Dim result As String
    
    LArray = Split(str, ",")
    
    For Each word In LArray
        ParseList = ParseList & "<aa>" & word & "</aa>"
    Next word
End Function
```

Comment: `Debug.Print "<aa>" & Join(Evaluate(Replace(Replace(Range("A1").Value, "[", "{"), "]", "}")), "</aa><aa>") & "</aa>"`